# Need to use ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentDictionary side by side

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have a requirement where messages can be added to a `ConcurrentQueue` in parallel. And I have a thread which reads messages and logs them at frequent intervals. I don't want to repeat the same message logged multiples times in that interval, instead i want to log it as message X repeated Y times in Z amount of time. I want to keep the order of occurrence of messages. For keeping the count I am using `ConcurrentDictionary` I tried few ways but its getting a bit complicated with extra lock. Can I fulfill my requirement without needing any extra lock.

Comment: Avoiding locks usually increases complexity in exchange for better performance.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes may be, but i would like to see some solutions even if the complexity is not good. Assume my queue doesn't have many different messages at any point of time.

Comment: If you're going to `lock` over access to the collections, there's no sense using the `Concurrent` namespace versions, just use the traditional versions.  Not sure why you'd think using a `lock` is complex, you throw a `lock` around a method that adds an item to both or takes an item from both.  It's the same as the non-concurrent version but without a `lock`.  Trying to manage it without using a `lock` would be *much* harder, and likely would require you writing a custom collection from scratch.

Comment: @Servy I thought if I had any better solution than making every enqueue and dequeue operation sequential with a single lock.

Comment: In theory, you do, however it will be an enormous amount of work, and will be very complex and error prone, and will only make a meaningful difference if there is an enormous amount of contention of the locks, and even then, the performance difference will not be *that* huge.  Unless this is a *super* performance critical application, and you've shown that you don't have the ability to get by without a basic `lock`, you should try to get by with a basic `lock`.